# MySQL doesn't create database as utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql

I am using this code to make a database with utf8_general_ci

```
CREATE DATABASE xxx
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    
use xxx;

SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'xxx';
```

When I get the result of schema is:

[image]

I don't understand why I can use utf8_general.ci.

By code it says the framework doesn't support utf8mb3_general_ci.

What I can I try next?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

Comment: for me its the same. utf8_general_ci. not sure why you are seeing this.

Comment: MySQL UTF-8 implementation used to be incomplete, since it only allocated 3 bytes (the encoding currently needs up to 4). For backward compatibility, instead of fixing the existing encoding they created a new one called `utf8mb4`. If you're trying to use actual UTF-8, you have your name wrong. If you're trying to use the old partial implementation, everything's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got the solution:

as @P.Salmon said **utf8** is an alias of **utf8mb3**, I based in this comment. I had installed version of mysql 8.0.31. I came back to version 8.0.25 and after to dump the database, as utf8, and setting all dll of Framework to 8.25 finally worked.

I share this if you are in the same situation. I don't know why mysql.data.EntityFramework 8.0.31 doesn't support **utf8mb3**.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259

Comment: This was supposedly fixed in MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.28 according to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105516, but users in bug 107259 still report errors with later releases of the connector.

Comment: I tested using 8.0.31. just changed the version 8.0.25 it worked